# Faster alternative to melt and rbind

Tags: r, data.table, rbind, melt

I have a big list of character vectors which looks something like this:

```
List of 53095
 $ 30875  : chr [1:10] "<h2 class=\"buildings-page-title buildings- ...
 $ 30876  : chr [1:10] "<h2 class=\"buildings-page-title buildings- ...
```

I want to create a data.table (or a data frame) with a single column. So what I did was:

```
# require(purr); require(data.table)
clean.data<-function(input){
  output1<-map(input, melt)
  output2<-data.frame()
 for (i in 1:length(output1)) { 
  output2<-rbind(output2, output1[[i]])

 }
 return(output2)}
```

Using a test data as an example, what I want is

```
test<-list(c("hello", "world", "!"), c("Nice","to","meet","you"))
print(clean.data(test))
> print(clean.data(test))
  value
1 hello
2 world
3     !
4  Nice
5    to
6  meet
7   you
```

But this function is incredibly slow, perhaps because my dataset is large, but I think my code is bad. Would there be any other more efficient way to get the same results?

Comment: Good call asking on this one. You are having a bunch of slow-down because of your code. For each loop in your code R has to figure out how much to expand the output2 dataframe, then check to make sure the data is compatible, then combine the data. Expanding output2 takes a long time in memory. Using a function from the solution below will help. Or, if you want to do things in a loop you can first set the size of output2 before entering the loop doing something like `output2 <- character(length(mylist))` which allocate a large [empty] vector in memory for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A faster way would be to `unlist` it and create a single column `data.frame`

```
data.frame(value = unlist(test))
```